# Passing values for multi-value parameter in SSRS query string

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have two reports built using SSRS 2005.  The first report is set to navigate to the second when a specific field is clicked.  I am using an expression similar to the following in the "Jump to URL" property of the textbox:

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://server/reportserver?%2fFolder%2fMyReport&rs:Command=Render&Date=" & Fields!Date.Value & "&MachineId=" & Fields!Machine.Value & "'))"
```

There is a multi-value parameter on the second report.  I need to pass multiple values for this parameter in the URL query string when calling this report.  Is there a way to pass multiple values for a parameter in the query string of a report? Or can you pass a parameter that will cause the Select All value to be selected?

Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just add additional query string parameters.

For example, to pass the parameters

```
Date:       2009-06-01
MachineID:  Machine1, Machine2, Machine3, Machine4
```

to a report named `Folder\MyReport` on a server named `server`, you would use the URL:

```
http://server/reportserver?%2fFolder%2fMyReport&rs:Command=Render&Date=2009-06-01&MachineId=Machine1&MachineId=Machine2&MachineId=Machine3&MachineId=Machine4
```

Comment: Working Perfect, I was stuck with this one long time ago. thanks

Comment: This is not working for me... 

`System.ServiceModel.FaultException: This report requires a default or user-defined value for the report parameter 'codListaPrioridade'. To run or subscribe to this report, you must provide a parameter value.`

Any advice?

Comment: @MarceloBarbosa, it sounds like you are not passing `codListaPrioridade`.  Your query should look like `[...]&codListaPrioridade=value1&codListaPrioridade=value2`.

Comment: This link is invalid now.  Can you explain your answer in text format?

Comment: @BrianPressler, the link was never valid.  It is the format of the URL you should use if you are passing multiple values to a paramter.  Replace `http://server/reportserver/` with your server, and the report name and parameters with your report's name and parameters.

Comment: Ah... gotcha... sorry I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 6):

Use `join(Parameters!<name>.Value,"&<param_name>=")` in the url for multivalued parameters.

If you are passing these parameters into a dataset you need to do a `join(Parameters!<param name>.Value)` when you pass the parameter in and then use a split function in SQL.  This one works well:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitParam]
   (@RepParam nvarchar(4000), @Delim char(1)= ',')
RETURNS @Values TABLE (Param nvarchar(4000))AS
  BEGIN
  DECLARE @chrind INT
  DECLARE @Piece nvarchar(100)
  SELECT @chrind = 1 
  WHILE @chrind > 0
    BEGIN
      SELECT @chrind = CHARINDEX(@Delim,@RepParam)
      IF @chrind  > 0
        SELECT @Piece = LEFT(@RepParam,@chrind - 1)
      ELSE
        SELECT @Piece = @RepParam
      INSERT  @Values(Param) VALUES(CAST(@Piece AS VARCHAR))
      SELECT @RepParam = RIGHT(@RepParam,LEN(@RepParam) - @chrind)
      IF LEN(@RepParam) = 0 BREAK
    END
  RETURN
  END
```

I recommend using the single valued method if the end user does not have to select the parameters directly since it saves you 2 characters per parameter in the url.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff!!  This is exactly what I needed - couldn't find this anywhere else on the web.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to do a similar thing to OP, and found putting this `&rp:mySelectAllParameter=<ALL>` in the url works to select all