# Append report parameter in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, reportingservices-2005

I have two parameters in the SSRS report(Company and Department).'Department' Parameter is dependent on the value you select from Company.
For Example, Company :A --> Department:x or Department:y (Company A has 2 department x and y)

I am trying to append the parameters in the Report URL by using `&rp:Company=A` this works fine.

But when i try to append the Second Parameter `&rp:Company=A&Department=x` in the URL it does not pick the second parameter value ,i.e. it selects Company as 'A' but unable to select the Department as 'x'.

what would be a correct way to append second parameter?

I have tried using `&rs:Command=Render&Company=A&Department=x` but this does not work.

Comment: you can look at this url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261433/passing-values-for-multi-value-parameter-in-ssrs-query-string
Also ssrs IS CASE SENSITIVE unlike sql server side.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/213b9d3c-47b6-4046-a4da-d20f34794d01/passing-multivalue-parameter-in-url-in-ssrs-2008-not-working?forum=sqlreportingservices